# How do you create standalone XML nodes in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How do you create a standalone XML node in .NET?

I have an XMLElement type that I'm trying to set a value to, but since the constructor for that class is protected, it won't let me do it.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement foo = xmldoc.CreateElement("", "foo"); ;
        XmlElement bar = xmldoc.CreateElement("", "bar"); ;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately the way the `XmlElement` works is that is always needs to be associated with a document.

Comment: Use Linq to Xml - you can create XElement. With the Xml DOM XmlElement has to belong to an Xml Document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
 public XElement ToXml()
 {
   XElement element = new XElement("Song",
                    new XElement("", "foo"),
                    new XElement("", "bar"));

   return element;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use XElement from System.Xml.Linq instead of the old XmlElement from System.Xml it allows you to do that very easily:

```
new XElement("foo")
```

Comment: The Linq XML Dom is sooooo much better.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the past:

```
            System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

            XmlElement fundsElement = doc.CreateElement("funds");
            doc.AppendChild(fundsElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you on .NET 3.5 or later?

```
using System.Xml.Linq;


var element = new XElement("foo", "bar");
Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
```

Output:

```
<foo>bar</foo>
```